# Facebook Page not showing in Graph API - I am an admin

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, graph

I have an application which publishes to Facebook pages, however I was just made an admin on a client's Facebook page so that I can get a access token via the Graph API.

The thing is it doesn't show up in the drop down list on the Graph API when I click "get token".

All the other pages I am admin on show up, just not this latest one, and as a test I created a random test page after being made admin and it shows up in the drop down.

Is there an additional setting that I am missing?

Comment: Request `/me/accounts`, and see if the page shows up in there.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it cannot be solved with programming knowledge, but instead requires support from Facebook.

Comment: This answer may help you:- [Facebook API me/accounts returns not all pages](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76340626/12326605)